# How can I read delay of a note that I am playing

Tags: arduino-uno, c#

I am playing note tone with CapacitiveSensor and an output of tone
like this

```
void loop() {   
    time_before = millis(); 

    long total1 =  cs_2_3.capacitiveSensor(30);
    long total2 =  cs_2_4.capacitiveSensor(30);


    if((total1>200)||(total2>200)) {

        if(total1>200) {

            tone(12,261); 
            time_after = millis();
            Serial.print("Time: ");
            Serial.println(time_after-time_before);
        }
        if(total2>200) {   
             tone(12,294);   
             time_after = millis();
             Serial.print("Time: ");
             Serial.println(time_after-time_before);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I read how many seconds I play this note par example

Comment: You are not calling `noTone()` anywhere, and you are calling `tone()` with two args, so the duration is indefinite. Perhaps you should add more conditional statements to detect when the "press" is released, and stop the tone there, as well as calculate the note length.

Comment: @uint128_t - Your comment is the correct answer to this OP's question. You should post it as an answer. As it stands only the _code execution time_ is measured, and **not** the _tone duration_, and it is the latter which is the OP's real goal.

Comment: @Greenonline Your answer looks pretty good, so I will upvote that :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently will only measure the code execution time and **not** the duration of the note(s) being played.

You need to follow [uint128_t's suggestion](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/32715/how-can-i-read-delay-of-a-note-that-i-am-playing#comment64941_32715) and rewrite the code to detect the "button release", at which point you measure the time with `millis()`, **and** call `noTone()`. Only then will you be able to measure the note's duration.

I believe that the source of confusion is that you seem to think that `tone()` acts like `delay()` and waits for the note to finish - it **does not**. `tone()` merely starts the note and then the next instruction is executed, without waiting for the note to end.

So, using `millis()` straight after calling `tone()` will actually only measure the time it takes to execute the `tone()` statement (and a few `if` statements - depending on whether you use your original code, or [Maximus's code](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/32715/how-can-i-read-delay-of-a-note-that-i-am-playing#answer-32718)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void loop(){              
    long total1 =  cs_2_3.capacitiveSensor(30);
    long total2 =  cs_2_4.capacitiveSensor(30);    

    if((total1>200)||(total2>200)){

        if(total1>200){
            time_before = millis();
            tone(12,261); 
            time_after = millis();

            Serial.print("Time: ");
            Serial.println(time_after-time_before);
        }

        if(total2>200){ 
            time_before = millis();  
            tone(12,294);   
            time_after = millis();

            Serial.print("Time: ");
            Serial.println(time_after-time_before);
        }
    }
}
```

Use code indentation if you can. Also, that first `OR` (`||`) is unnecessary. I think you need to re-write this, or is this what you wanted?

Comment: I cant use delay(1000).....

Comment: That is just a sample code. The author put that there to slow down the data rate between arduino and PC. You could ignore that, the code would work fine. Anyway, for your function, you don't need to use delay.

Comment: Time: 158
Time: 159
Time: 157
Time: 159
Time: 158
Time: 157
Time: 159
Time: 158
Time: 155

Comment: if i don't use no delay this is the output have
it's not correct

Comment: i want the somme of all the time

Comment: If you wrote the code correctly, this would mean that your function takes around 160 ms to run.

Comment: I put my code and the output 
what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the code?

Comment: yes i tried the code 
result is 0 or 1

Comment: It seems that the OP wants the time of one complete loop cycle ("_i want the somme of all the time_"), whereas your code, due to the new placement of the `time_before = millis();` will only give the time of each `tone()` call. Maybe an additional `time_loop_start = millis();` is required at the beginning of the loop and then have an additional `Serial.println(time_after-time_loop_start);` at the very end of the loop.  However, this will still only measure the code execution time, and _not_ the length of the note, which is what I suspect is the OP's real goal.